# high school line equation question

Tags: geometry

I hit stumbling block below.
But i try everything that I can think of but i failed to find any satisfactory answer.
my workout is that I find mid point between point B and C.
and then using A and earlier mid point to find slope which I know is perpendicular.
But line equation y = mx + c didn't match with answer at the back.

the problem is as below:
Let A(1,1), B(4,5), and C(6,13) be points in the xy-plane.
Find the equation of the line which bisects $\angle$BAC.

The solution given is 7x - 4y = 3

your help is much appreciated.

Comment: The angle bisector in general does not pass through the midpoint.  Is this in a section about trig identities?

Comment: To see why the midpoint doesn't help, observe that if I move $C$ along $AC$ towards $A$, then the midpoint $M$ between $B$ and $C$ moves towards the line $AB$. Hence the angle between $AB$ and $AM$ changes, but you want that to be exactly half the angle between $AB$ and $AC$, which is not changing.

Comment: it's not about trig identities, this is more of 'refresher' question in multivariable calculus book.benmachine, so it's not simple as just using y=mx+c equation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know (or perhaps, remember) that the angle bisector is the locus of all points that are equidistant from both angle's rays? In this case, the angle rays are the lines $\,AB\,,\,AC\,$:$$AB:\,4x-3y-1=0\,\,,\,AC:\,12x-5y-7=0$$So we want all the points $\,(x,y)\,$ which are at the same distance from both lines above: $$\frac{|4x-3y-1|}{\sqrt{4^2+3^2}}=\frac{|12x-5y-7|}{\sqrt{12^2+5^2}}\Longrightarrow 13^2(4x-3y-1)^2=5^2(12x-5y-7)^2\Longrightarrow$$Try to continue from here.

**Added** In fact you don't need the headache of the squares in the last line right: just check the left side with different values for the absolute values (once $\,|A|\,=A\,,\,\,another\,\,with\,\,|A|=-A\,$), taking into account that both lines $\,AB\,,\,AC\,$ have positive slope and thus the bisector line has also to have positive slope...and between the first two lines' slopes)

**Further added:** Drop the squares but you can not drop the absolute values, so we get $$13|4x-3y-1|=5|12x-5y-7|\Longrightarrow 52x-39y-13=\pm\left(60x-25y-35\right)$$$$(i) \,\,52x-39y-13=60x-25y-35\Longrightarrow 8x+14y-22=0$$and this is not what we want as both given lines have positive slope (and thus their angle's bisector also has positive slope, so we get here the bisector of the *obtuse* angle between the lines, which is usually NOT "the angle between the lines", defined almost always as the acute (or straight) one between), so we go with $$(ii)\,\,52x-39y-13=-60x+25y+35\Longrightarrow 112x-64y=48\Longrightarrow 7x-4y=3$$and we get what we wanted.

Of course, there's also a well-known formula with tangents and difference of angles and stuff, but on purpose I left trigonometry out of the answer.

Comment: i think both equation on the right should not have square of 2(ie: 13(4x-3y-1)=5(12x-5y-7))?Although I work this out, I still failed to satisfy the textbook solution 7x - 4y = 3.

Comment: @kypronite Well, of course you can take off the squares (in fact, strongly adviced to do so!) but then you must let the absolute values...I'll add something to my answer.

Comment: my answer that I find is indeed 8x+4y-22 which is wrong.
I look at your workout and indeed it's much clearer now.
I will try to study more in depth the solutions you provided 
once i return home as I'm at work now.
I'm not good at interpreting\visualize math terms,
so I failed to follow the hints you provided earlier.
Also, thanks for your help, this really help me a lot :D

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, your method doesn't quite work. But it almost does.

If you extend $AB$ to a point $D$ so that $AD$ and $AC$ have the same length, you can find the midpoint of $CD$ and then continue as you did earlier. That same procedure should now produce the correct result.

Comment: how do i elegantly extend to point D so AD and AC have same length.Seem to me I need to calculate length AC (theorem pythagoras) and keep guessing point D until both AD and AC have same length.

Comment: No need to guess. Say that $m$ is the length of $AB$ and $n$ that of $AC$. Then $D=(n/m)(B-A)+A$. You are simply scaling by the ratio of the two lengths.

Comment: Also, it might be helpful to shift the coordinates so that $A$ is located at the origin, in order to simplify your calculations. Just remember to shift back afterwards!

Comment: sorry for late reply as i posted late at night and i have to work the next day.I just tried your method and confirm the answer is as expected.Thanks for your help :)